# Find and print elements name with MongoDB and Mangoose with Node.js then disconnect to the server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoDB with mongoose I created a fruit collection and I want to print the fruits names then disconnect to the server

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ //schema: come vogliamo che gli eleemnti vengano sturtturati
  name: String,

  rating: {
    type: Number,
    min: 1,
    max: 10
  },
  review: String
});

//creiamo un modulo
const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 8,
  review: "good"
});
//fruit.save();
const kiwi = new Fruit({
  name: "Kiwi",
  rating: 10,
  review: "great"
});

Fruit.find(function(err, fruits) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    mongoose.connection.close();
    fruits.forEach(function(fruit) {
      console.log(fruit.name);
    });
  }
});
```

I've written this in the app.js then I compiled it with the command "node app.js"
The terminal gives me this:

Apple
Apple
Apple
Apple
Kiwi

(node:24352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoExpiredSessionError: Cannot use a session that has ended
at Object.applySession (C:\Users\Feder\Desktop\udemy\mongooseFruit\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sessions.js:647:16)
at Connection.command (C:\Users\Feder\Desktop\udemy\mongooseFruit\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:185:36)
at C:\Users\Feder\Desktop\udemy\mongooseFruit\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:176:18
at Object.callback (C:\Users\Feder\Desktop\udemy\mongooseFruit\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:266:13)
at C:\Users\Feder\Desktop\udemy\mongooseFruit\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:474:29
at C:\Users\Feder\Desktop\udemy\mongooseFruit\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:402:13
at callback (C:\Users\Feder\Desktop\udemy\mongooseFruit\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:52:9)
at C:\Users\Feder\Desktop\udemy\mongooseFruit\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:124:13
at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\Users\Feder\Desktop\udemy\mongooseFruit\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:479:9)
at MessageStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:24352) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:24352) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to save your models to database first.

Second of all looks like you are using the `find` method in wrong way.

```
const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 8,
  review: "good"
});

fruit.save();

const kiwi = new Fruit({
  name: "Kiwi",
  rating: 10,
  review: "great"
});

kiwi.save();

Fruit.find({}).then((fruits) => {         
    mongoose.connection.close();
    fruits.forEach(function(fruit) {
      console.log(fruit.name);
    });
});
```

Also I would suggest to use `async/await` to improve code readability.

Comment: "Second of all looks like you are using the find method in wrong way."  what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that parameters are wrong. You should always pass the first parameter, a filter object. 

If my answer solved your concern, please mark it as correct.

Comment: it create the same problem

Comment: Ok, I changed my answer try again. Now it is using promises instead of callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
const fruits = await Fruit.find({})
// do whatever you want with fruits
mongoose.connection.close();
```

It looks like you are trying to close the connection while still using it. By using await you're gonna wait that the query is over before closing the connection.